# Azure DevOps pipeline to push container image to Azure Function not working

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I am working on Azure DevOps to create a pipeline to get code from GitHub, create a docker image, build it, then publish it to Azure Container Registry, then deploy a function app with that latest image. I have tried to push to the Azure Function app quite a few times, with different errors each time. Sometimes, the requriements.txt file is not downloaded and the app can't use the required packages, other times, the app just doesn't work with Azure Function Runtime not working. I suspect the issue is with the Yaml file that I am using, but I can't figure out how it works. Would really appreciate some help!

Current Yaml file:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: acr
  imageRepository: avhcrepo
  containerRegistry: avhc
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: 'latest'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'test123'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      displayName: Download build artifacts
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'test123'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
    - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Demo Cybriant Subscription(fdbcdaa8-f501-435c-ac25-39179b43db0b)'
        appType: 'functionAppLinux'
        appName: 'demo-avhealthcheck' # replace with the name of your Azure Function
        package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
      displayName: Deploy Azure Function
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

Comment: Well, for starters, the `AzureFunctionApp@1` step *does nothing with the container image*. Try `AzureFunctionAppContainer@1`, or look at the documentation for function apps to see how to configure them to pull from a container.

Comment: Thanks! I made that change. The yaml file now only has a buildandPush stage, and a deploy stage. However now I am getting an "Azure Functions Runtime Unreachable" error!

Comment: Sounds like you need to troubleshoot the potential causes of that error. There are a lot of reasons you could be getting it, and without knowing how you are provisioning your function app and how it's currently configured, it's difficult to suggest anything.